# Prolog: List management with indexes

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate to add elements in a list according to a common index. What I done so far is certainly not worth showing... =(

The expected behavior would be something like:

```
List = [ ]

add_to_list( List, Index1, Param1, Value1 )
List = [
    [ Index1, [ Param1, Value1 ] ]
]

add_to_list( List, Index1, Param2, Value2 )
List = [
    [ Index1, [ Param1, Value1 ], [ Param2, Value2 ] ]
]

add_to_list( List, Index2, Param3, Value3 )
List = [
    [ Index1, [ Param1, Value1 ], [ Param2, Value2 ] ],
    [ Index2, [ Param3, Value3 ] ]
]
```

Comment: Show what you have done anyway. It proves you tried, and may reveal the defect in your understanding of Prolog.

Comment: Proves I tried? That sounds coercive... =D

Comment: Yes, it proves this isn't your homework which you're just too lazy to do. The Prolog tag is 90% people taking a class who don't want to do the homework themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by doing this:

```
add_to_list( [ ], Param, Val, Val2, [ [ Param, [ [ Val, Val2 ] ] ] ] ).
add_to_list( L, Param, Val, Val2, LNew ) :-
    member( [ Param, Vals ], L ) ->
    (   select( [ Param, Vals ], L, L2 ),
        not( member( [ Val, Val2 ], Vals ) ) ->
        (   append( Vals, [ [ Val, Val2 ] ], Vals2 ),
            append( [ [ Param, Vals2 ] ], L2, LNew )
        );  append( L, L2, LNew )
    );  append( L, [ [ Param, [ Val, Val2 ] ] ], LNew ).
```

So the behavior is:

```
List1 = []

add_to_list( List1, Index1, Param1, Value1, List2 )
List2 = [
    [ Index1, [ [ Param1, Value1 ] ] ]
]

add_to_list( List2, Index1, Param2, Value2, List3 )
List3 = [
    [ Index1, [ [ Param1, Value1 ], [ Param2, Value2 ] ] ]
]

add_to_list( List3, Index2, Param3, Value3, List4 )
List4 = [
    [ Index1, [ [ Param1, Value1 ], [ Param2, Value2 ] ] ],
    [ Index2, [ [ Param3, Value3 ] ] ]
]
```

Thanks, thanosQR.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this behaviour is impossible (unless we hack prolog to pieces with stuff like `setarg/3`).
(for more details check d[estructive vs single assignment](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Destructive_assignment))

A pretty similar behaviour would be:

```
List0 = [ ]

add_to_list( List0, Index1, Param1, Value1, List1)
List1 = [
    [ Index1, [ Param1, Value1 ] ]
]

add_to_list( List1, Index1, Param2, Value2, List2)
List2 = [
    [ Index1, [ Param1, Value1 ], [ Param2, Value2 ] ]
]

add_to_list( List2, Index2, Param3, Value3, List3)
List3 = [
    [ Index1, [ Param1, Value1 ], [ Param2, Value2 ] ],
    [ Index2, [ Param3, Value3 ] ]
]
```

Of course, since we dont do separate stuff with `Param` and `Value` we can just pass them as one variable:
`add_to_list(List1, Index, Val, List2)` where `Val = [Param, Value]`

A simple implementation would be:

add_to_list(L1, I, Val, L2):-
  member([I,Rest],L1) ->
    ( append(Val,Rest,FRest),
      select([I,Rest], L1, [I,FRest], L2)
    ) ; append([[I,Val]], L1).

But this is quite slow; it's much faster (and easier!) to add the new elements to the head of the list.

Last, it's probably best to use [association lists](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.3%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/assoc.html%27%29%29) which, to my experience, are very fast and can easily model your problem